# Visual Studio 2008 hangs with XAML

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xaml

I know this is not a programming question per-se, but it's still related in a way. Anyway, I've had this problem for months now, and right now I decided to start searching on Google, but I can't find anything. It doesn't only hang for a few seconds, each time this happens, I have to restart visual studio.

@John Saunders: Thanks for pointing that out.

It hangs when I go to a XAML file on my project, this is very random, I think the problem happens specifically when it's trying to render the design view. But that's just my guess.

If anyone had the problem and solved it, it would make my day if you could pass on your solution!

Thanks.

Comment: It will help if you say what your problem is! "hangs with XAML" - does it hang if there's a XAML file in the project? If it's selected? If it's opened with the XML editor?

Comment: Could it be this bug?  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=366606

and here some work around http://community.sgdotnet.org/blogs/maungmaung/archive/2009/09/25/xaml-programming-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Right-click a xaml file in the Solution Explorer and click "Open with..."

Then set the "Source Code (Text) Editor" as the default. This will prevent the "Design" view from trying to open and hogging a lot of resources. You'll still have code highlighting and Intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that your problem have something to do with the render in design time of the Visual Studio.
Visual Studio can't do the render and throw a error, don't add your controls in design time try to add your XAML controls in runtime, that is the way I use and work fine. 
For a example of how to do it, see how Visual Studio does it.